# Building a dynamic table/div grid that works on different screensizes

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I am about to build a grid like this:

```
                       <- 100px ->
       +---------------+---------+ -
       | contentbox    | Right   | |
     - +---------------+     box | | 80 %
25px | | bottombox     |         | |
     - +---------------+---------+ -
       <--------- 80 % ---------->
```

My current problem is to build this flexible. The box itself have a size of 80% of the width of the users browser window. Contentbox should be able to adjust itself accordingly, all the other boxes is somewhat fixed sized.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried doing it like this with tables:

```
<table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</td>
    <td width="200" rowspan="2">rightbox<br />
    rightbox<br />
rightbox<br />
rightbox<br />
rightbox<br />
rightbox<br />
rightbox<br />
rightbox<br />
rightbox<br />
rightbox<br />
rightbox<br />
rightbox<br />
rightbox</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="25">bottombox</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But it seems like that no matter what I do, the bottombox will always get half the height of the rightbox.

But I would prefer doing it with divs.

Comment: I don't see the problem here. What have you tried?

Comment: See my edit, there is my first approach

Comment: Actually I think that this is one of the ultra rare dark-magic-cloaked cases where a table is actually needed. I'll do some testing and get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a something like what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/zLGez/

If you need equal columns or have other requirements — update your question and I'll update my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Give contentBox and bottombox a right margin of 100px.  Then use float on the right box to make it fill the space where this margin is located.  that will handle the layout within another container that takes care of the 80% width (easy enough) and 80% height (a bit more complicated).